# Design stack so that getminimum, pop, push & top all takes O(1)

Tags: stack, adt

so I was asked this question:

Consider the ADT stack. In addition to the operations Push, Pop
and Top, we want to support a new operation FindMin, which returns the smallest
element in the stack. Design the data structure and algorithms to support these
operations such that each of the four operations (Push, Pop, Top and FindMin) takes
constant time. No need to check the over and under conditions and no need
to give the procedures for Empty and Full. [Hint: use an extra stack.]

So I have seen some answers but they all seemed to take O(n) time once the FindMin function is used. And I don't really get what the hint is trying to tell me...Please help me!!! Thankssss!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackWithMin extends Stack<Integer> {

private Stack<Integer> minStack;

public StackWithMin () {
    minStack = new Stack<Integer>();    
}

public void push(int value){
    if (value <= min()) { // Note the '=' sign here
        minStack.push(value);
    }

    super.push(value);
}

public Integer pop() {
    int value = super.pop();

    if (value == min()) {
        minStack.pop();         
    }

    return value;
}

public int min() {
    if (minStack.isEmpty()) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else {
        return minStack.peek();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    StackWithMin stackWithMin = new StackWithMin();
    stackWithMin.push(7);
    stackWithMin.push(5);
    stackWithMin.push(6);
    stackWithMin.push(7);
    stackWithMin.push(4);
    System.out.println(stackWithMin.min());
    stackWithMin.pop();
    System.out.println(stackWithMin.min());
}
```

}